# how to setup admin-lte-express nodejs project

Tags: node.js, adminlte

I tried to setup project mentioned at this github location  https://github.com/RamEduard/admin-lte-express
 I created a sample express application  where  files are like this:-

Package.json

```
{
 "name": "apr27",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
 "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"admin-lte-express": "^1.4.2",
"express": "^4.16.3"
}
}
```

Index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use('/admin', express.static('./node_modules/admin-lte-express/public'))
app.use('/', require('admin-lte-express'));

app.listen(3001, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3001!'))
```

when I hit server localhost:3000, It returns me error page. Can anybody help me why it is happening and what is correct way to do it

Comment: i believe you must have a app.get('/yourURL', function(req,res){//your logic here}

Comment: I assume you have noteiced this yourself but your are listening to port 3001 rather than port 3000.
So go to localhost:3001 rather than localhost:3000

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the below steps:

## 1) Install admin lte via npm using

npm install admin-lte

## 2) Add this path in index.js or server.js

app.use('/admin', express.static('./node_modules/admin-lte'));